# Jquery trigger when PDF file downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf plug-in for generating pdf. I am showing message and spinner when user click on pdf link and i want to hide that when pdf is generated and pushed to browser for download/show. I have added jquery code on body onload which will not execute. Is there any other way to trigger jquery function when pdf file pushed to browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather complicated issue, but can be solved nicely if you are willing to use jQuery plugins. http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/ is a plugin that can do exactly what you need if I understood you correctly.

---

My frontend code looks like this

```
$.fileDownload('/Content/Print', {
    successCallback: function (url) {
        $("#PrintingMessage").dialog('close');
    },
    failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
        $("#PrintingMessage").dialog('close');

        if (responseHtml.indexOf('Error403') != -1) {
            $("#PrintingFailedMessage").html("Error 403.");
        } else if (responseHtml.indexOf('Error500') != -1) {
            $("#PrintingFailedMessage").html("Error 500.");
        }

        $("#PrintingFailedMessage").dialog({ modal: true });
    },
    httpMethod: "POST",
    data: $('#PublishForm').serialize()
});
```

And my backend does this at the end of the process. You'll have to translate that yourself :)

```
Response.SetCookie(new System.Web.HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });
return File(file, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
```

Comment: I have used this same plugin but somehow my modal window shows up on click for fraction of a second and then disappears.If I click on the link again while the file download is in progress the modal window shows up and stays. Once I get the file save browser window, the modal window does not close. 
I have used the jquery.fileDownload.js v1.3.2 and added class 'fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience' to my link. The JS code for click event is as follows (the one mentioned in the blog).Also, as mentioned in the blog I am setting a cookie with the name 'fileDownload' to true. Any clue what is missing?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. It can be a pain to get working, I had some issues too, did you get it up and running? I'm not at a place where I could check my solution but I'll try to figure it out tomorrow if I remember :)

Comment: That's my code. Add a `debugger;` to the JavaScript if it fails for you. Other than that I don't really know what to might be going wrong with your code unfortunately. My PrintingMessage is a dialog that has a button that starts the printing process by among other things calling that JavaScript.